# JQuery: How to save dynamically added form inputs after validation fails in cakePHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation, cakephp

I have a problem with my registration form. So, I have some fields that are generetad when user click on link, and those fields are lost after I press form Submit button if validation fails. If validation pass, everything is correct and data is saved into database.

So these are that fields, and also script to add new field:

```
<script> 
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var MaxInputs       = 8; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var FacebookInputsWrapper   = $("#FacebookInputsWrapper"); //Input boxes wrapper ID
    var AddButton       = $("#FacebookAddMoreFileBox"); //Add button ID

    var x = FacebookInputsWrapper.length; //initlal text box count
    var FieldCount=0; //to keep track of text box added

    $(AddButton).click(function (e)  //on add input button click
    {
        if(x <= MaxInputs) //max input box allowed
        {

        FieldCount++; //text box added increment
        //add input box
        $(FacebookInputsWrapper).append('<div style="margin-top:10px;"><input id="SocialMediaLink' + FieldCount + 'Link" type="hidden" name="data[SocialMediaLink][' + FieldCount + '][type]" value="fb" /><input id="SocialMediaLink' + FieldCount + 'Link" type="text" name="data[SocialMediaLink][' + FieldCount + '][link]" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Facebook link" /><a style="background:0;color:black;" href="#" class="facebookremoveclass">&times;</a></div>');
        x++; //text box increment
        }
    return false;
    });

    $("body").on("click",".facebookremoveclass", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        if( x > 1 ) {
            $(this).parent('div').remove(); //remove text box
            x--; //decrement textbox
        }
    return false;
    }) 

  });
  </script>
```

HTML

```
<li><label>Facebook</label>
<div >
  <div style="float:right; margin-top:10px;" id="FacebookInputsWrapper"><?php echo $this->Form->input('SocialMediaLink.0.type',array('type'=>'hidden','value'=>'fb')); ?><?php echo $this->Form->input('SocialMediaLink.0.link',array('type'=>'text','class'=>'input-xlarge','label'=>false,'div'=>false,'placeholder'=>'Facebook link', 'error' => array(
    'attributes' => array('class' => 'inputerror')
))); ?><label  style="color:#FF0000;"><?php echo @$valid_social; ?></label>
  <a style="margin-left:10px;background : 0;color:black;" href="#" id="FacebookAddMoreFileBox">Add another Facebook account</a></div>

</div>
```

So my question is: is it possible to save dynamically generated form fields and their values after validation fails and how?

Thank you

Comment: Which validation are you talking about here? Is it jQuery validation, custom validation, CakePHP validation...? If your data is saving fine after a successful validation then you know there must be something happening on an unsuccessful validation that is causing those fields not to be saved... Please share more relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question properly, you need to show those dynamically created fields in your view after validation has failed.  Do it like this, checking `$this->request->data` for  those fields:

```
            <?if (!empty($this->request->data['SocialMediaLink'])):?>
                <?foreach($this->request->data['SocialMediaLink'] as $i => $item):?>
                    <div style="margin-top:10px;">
                        <?=$this->Form->hidden('SocialMediaLink.' . $i . '.type', array('value' => 'fb'))?>
                        <?=$this->Form->input('SocialMediaLink.' . $i . '.link')?>
                    </div>
                <?endforeach;?>
            <?endif;?>
```

Alternatively, you could trigger the click event on `AddButton` the right amount of times on page load, based on the number of elements in `$this->request->data['SocialMediaLink']`

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want. I will try this solution and reply here. Thank you very much.

Comment: Array to string conversion...so $i is array, how to get row number?

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in my code.  Try it again?

Comment: Thank you very much! This one works great! Maybe you know is it possible to have same funcionality now as I had with "click" event? As you can see in my JS code, I have "X" button next to each dynamically added input so I can remove that field if necessary. And also, I have limited inputs (maxInputs = 8), but when I use this code, it display all data fields that were not empty + 8 inputs more. Do you understand my question? And finally, thank you very much for this solution once again!